# If $n \to \infty$ and $r \to \infty$ so that $r/n \to p$, then $ {n - N \choose r-N}/ {n \choose r} \to p^N$.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

A random sample of size $r$ without replacement is taken from a population of $n$ elements. The probability $u_r$ that $N$ given elements will all be included in the sample is 
$$u_r = {n - N \choose r-N}/ {n \choose r}.$$
If $n \to \infty$ and $r \to \infty$ so that $r/n \to p$, then $u_r \to p^N$.

$u_r ={N\choose N} {n - N \choose r-N}/ {n \choose r} = {n - N \choose r-N}/ {n \choose r}$ (hyper-geometric distribution). I know that with large $n$, $u_r = {r \choose N}(N/n)^N (1-N/n)^{r-N}$ (binomial distribution) since with large $n$, sampling with replacement and without replacement become negligible. But, I am not sure how I can proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to add a "prove that" somewhere in your question to clarify what's being asked.

Comment: To prove the limit statement, you can expand the binomial coefficients into factorials and rearrange the expression into a product of $N$ fractions, each of which approaches $\frac rn$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express the $u_r$ in terms of factorials:

$$u_r = \frac{(n-N)!}{(r-N)!(n-r)!} . \frac{r!(n-r)!}{n!}$$

$$u_r = \frac{(n-N)!}{n!}.\frac{r!}{(r-N)!}$$

So on the given conditions of $n \to \infty$ and $r \to \infty$:

$$u_r =\lim_{r\to\infty \ and \ n\to\infty} \frac{(n-N)!}{n!}.\frac{r!}{(r-N)!}$$

$$=\lim \frac{r.(r-1)(r-2)...(r-N+1)}{n.(n-1)(n-2)...(n-N+1)}$$

$$=\lim \frac{r^N(1)(1-\frac{2}{r})(1-\frac{3}{r})...(1-\frac{(N-1)}{r})}{n^N(1)(1-\frac{2}{n})(1-\frac{3}{n})...(1-\frac{(N-1)}{n})}$$

$$u = \lim_{r\to\infty \ and \ n\to\infty} (\frac{r}{n})^N .(\frac{(1)(1-\frac{2}{r})(1-\frac{3}{r})...(1-\frac{(N-1)}{r})}{(1)(1-\frac{2}{n})(1-\frac{3}{n})...(1-\frac{(N-1)}{n})})$$

Apply the limit and the $\frac{r}{n}$ will become $p$ and the rest of the terms will converge to $1$ each.

$$\therefore u_r \to p^N$$